# How can I align several axis of different sizes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For the arrangement of different axis several options are mentioned in the pgfplots documentation and examples. Most consider only the case when all the axis have the same size.

How can I arrange and scale axis that differ in size?

Here the axis on the right side should be aligned with the top of the top left plot which works, and the bottom with the bottom of the bottom left plot, which does not work:

[image: misaligned axis]

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=left plot,
    width=4cm,
    scale only axis,
    ylabel=a,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    name=bottom plot,
    at={(left plot.below south west)},
    anchor=north west,
    width=4cm,
    scale only axis,
    ylabel=b,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    name=right plot,
    at={($(left plot.north east) + (1.5cm,0)$)},
    anchor=north west,
    width=4cm,
    height=8cm, % which height is appropriate here?
    scale only axis,
    ylabel=c,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you "only" need to know the `height`s used for the "left" plots and the distance of the plots (axis borders without labels, i.e. the black box) ...

Hope the code is self-explanatory. If not, don't hesitate to ask and I'll put in more comments.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    % use this `compat` level or higher to make use of the advanced axis label positioning
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % state common `axis` options here
    % (so we don't need to repeat ourselfes)
    /pgfplots/.cd,
        width=4cm,
        height=\Height,
        % (luckily you already had implemented this key, which makes it a bit
        %  easier to calculate the needed `height`)
        scale only axis,
    /tikz/.cd,
]
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\Height}{35mm}
%        % or, if you don't state a `height` explicitly use the default value
%        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\Height}{\axisdefaultheight}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xOffset}{15mm}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yOffset}{10mm}
    \begin{axis}[
        name=left plot,
        ylabel=a,
    ]
        \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        name=bottom plot,
        at={($ (left plot.south west) + (0,-\yOffset) $)},
        anchor=north west,
        ylabel=b,
    ]
        \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        name=right plot,
        at={($ (left plot.north east) + (\xOffset,0) $)},
        anchor=north west,
        height={2*\Height + \yOffset},
        ylabel=c,
    ]
        \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you. By making the spacing between the two left plots explicit the height of the right hand side can now be calculated. That works nicely here!

Comment: +1: Is the `/pgfplots/.cd,` and `/tikz/.cd,` needed in this example?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, because I am stating the stuff in the options of the `tikzpicture` environment you can either use the `.cd` or you need to prefix all PGFPlots options with `/pgfplots/`, e.g. `/pgfplots/width`. Most likely here the `/tikz/.cd` is not needed, because directly afterwards only PGFPlots stuff follows. But I didn't test and this should be the safe way in case there should follow TikZ options.